# msmq - trigger - standalone executable invocation not working

Tags: wcf, exe, msmq

I have been trying for the past few days to invoke an exe file by using msmq trigger. Its never being called. These are the steps I followed.

Created a trigger mentioning the queue path with peeking checked. Enabled Checked

Created a rule with no conditions so that the trigger will fire whenever a new message is obtained. And selected the radio button mentioning Standalone Executable. Provided the field with the correct location. Checked the location with RUN and confirmed that the exe is working.

But when a new message is being sent to the queue the exe is not being called.

Comment: Does the EXE appear in Task Manager even if you can't see it on the screen? I usually test with Notepad.exe as a nice, simple app to launch.

Comment: Also, add a condition that will always be true, like "label does not contain 'flibble'" in case it's the lack of a condition that's causing a problem.

Comment: It works perfectly with Windows XP. Having trouble with Windows 7 and Windows 8

Comment: But what about my suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same problem but I found that the exe is being launched as a background process.  I'm using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the "Microsoft Trigger service" is online?

I had a similar problem and restarting both the system and the Service helped!

Comment: Will check and revert.