# MSMQ Trigger opens executable as background process

Tags: windows, windows-8, message-queue, msmq, background-process

I'm using a Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ) Trigger to launch a standalone executable on Windows 8.1.  The exe was not launching so I tried opening Notepad instead ([thanks John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923609/msmq-trigger-standalone-executable-invocation-not-working#comment29672813_19923609)).  That did not work either so I peaked at the Task Manager and noticed that it was opening as a Background Process.

My question is: why does the application open as a background process and how do I prevent this?

Is it possible to add a launch Parameter, for example?

**Edit**

I should note that I'm okay with the exe running in the background once my application goes live.  I would like to prevent it from doing so during development, however.

Comment: application in background?? how do you do this? could you point the way? this would save me from developing a service app which is a pain to debug and install then uninstall to install updated code.

Comment: could a process running in the background start an app in the foreground? like calling show on a forms class?

Comment: @RadioSpace Hah, I wished I knew.  I'm not doing this intentionally; I'm guessing it has something to do with Window 8.1?  I'm not doing anything outside of the numerous, and basic, tutorials found around the web.