# msmq trigger not firing

Tags: triggers, msmq

I'm trying to run a MSMQ Trigger. I followed everything twice, and still, no go.

Here's my queue, with some messages

[image: msgs label]

I've added a trigger, with a peeking type, and a rule :

[image: trigger setup]

I've created a rule, if label contains "test1"

[image: rule setup]

I've made sure it has the permissions:

[image: trigger permissions]

Still, no go. Any ideas ?

Running on a Windows 7 machine.
Made sure the msmq trigger service is running (restarting it doesn't fix it up).

looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19923609/1698987), but didn't help. Also made sure process is not run as a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you are describing it - also on Windows 7.

By default the "Message Queuing Triggers" service is running as "Network Service". The program I wanted to run was in my user profile but "Network Service" has no access to that.

I moved the program to a folder under c:\Temp\ and updated the rule action to point to the new location.

(Alternatively changing the user for the service or granting file access to the "Network Service"-'user' may also work.)

Comment: Hmm. This might have been useful a year ago :). Dunno if it solves it because I don't have access to the code now. But I'll mark it as the answer since it's the best we have. If anyone else can comment/upvote please do so.